# OS X - Static routes / non-standard default gateway for endpoints on *local subnet*

Tags: linux, macos, networking, routing, netstat

My question is:  How can I reliably set up a static route in OS X, for 2 endpoints to pass via a gateway, where all machines are on the same subnet?  I provide the context below:

For testing purposes, I need to be able to set up a specific route between 2 endpoints on the same local subnet - an OS X (10.9) MacBook and a Linux-based 'receiver'.

The behaviour needs to be such that the next hop for traffic leaving the MacBook will be a FreeBSD-based QoS machine and not the standard default gateway.  The BSD machine may also sit on the same subnet, and performs SNAT to masquerade new traffic and re-translates upon return.

Simplified, my environment is similar to the following:

> Local subnet = 10.160.0.0/16
>     MacBook = 10.160.2.100
>     Linux Receiver = 10.160.2.200
>     Default Gateway for standard devices = 10.160.0.1

Example configuration of the BSD gateway:

> en0 10.160.2.160
>     en1 10.160.3.170
>     netmask 255.255.0.0
>     gateway 10.160.0.1

An example of the desired flow:

> REQUEST: MacBook --> BSD --> DefaultGateway --> Receiver
>     RESPONSE:  Receiver --> DefaultGateway --> BSD --> MacBook

I see 3 problems occurring:

1. If I set the default gateway for en0 (the only active interface) on
   OS X to be the BSD machine on say 10.160.2.160, this works for a
   while until this default route is automatically overwritten by OS X
   to be the standard default of 10.160.0.1
2. I am also running into issues when configuring static routes in OS X
   using:

   ```
   route add 10.160.2.200 10.160.2.160
   ```

   .. in this case one of 2 things happens - either the route works for a while displaying the netstat UGHS flags, and is then overwritten by OS X after which netstat includes the M flag to indicate that it was overwritten by a redirect..
3. ..or the route does not work at all as there must be some other route taking precedence.  Traceroute confirms this.

Netstat output after initial configuration:

```
jiosxserver:~ julianivory$ netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.160.2.160       UGSc           17        0     en0
10.140.1.31        10.160.2.160       UGHS            0        0     en0
10.140.1.35        10.160.1.1         UGHS            0        0     en0
10.160/16          link#4             UCS             5        0     en0
10.160.0.1         0:14:22:20:1c:d9   UHLWIir        14        0     en0   1191
10.160.1.37        0:50:56:8a:87:e9   UHLWIi          0        0     en0   1138
10.160.2.160       8e:af:b2:47:7f:91  UHLWIir         4        0     en0   1144
10.160.3.75        127.0.0.1          UHS             0        0     lo0
10.160.3.79        a8:20:66:27:72:2e  UHLWIi          0        1     en0   1184
10.160.255.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       44     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              9    20602     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
```

...and Traceroute output shows that the default route is not in use:

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.160.0.1 (10.160.0.1)  0.504 ms  0.237 ms  0.217 ms
 2  192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1)  1.065 ms  1.020 ms  0.973 ms
 3  name-removed (xx.1xx.xxx.1)  14.250 ms  13.688 ms  14.046 ms
 4  xxx.xxx.178.141 (xxx.xxx.178.141)  14.196 ms  14.121 ms  13.967 ms
```

...after some time, the default gateway will have 'automagically' been changed to 10.160.0.1...

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated hugely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may benefit from this - my primary issue was that other devices were sending ICMP redirects.  After disabling this on my local (OS X) machine, my static routes have been reliable.

In OS X this can be achieved on the fly by using sysctl:

```
/usr/sbin/sysctl -w net.inet.icmp.drop_redirect=1
/usr/sbin/sysctl -w net.inet.ip.redirect=0
```

This can also be set persistently within /etc/sysctl.conf

Answer (score 1):

This [link nails the answer](http://www.marcoach.nl/persistent-static-routes-on-os-x) for macOS static routes that are persistent across reboots with one additional piece of info for the situation in this question...gleaned from the networksetup command usage info.

From the networksetup (command line - use Terminal) :

```
Usage: networksetup -setadditionalroutes <networkservice> [ <dest> <mask> 
<gateway> ]*
   Set additional IPv4 routes associated with <networkservice>
   by specifying one or more [ <dest> <mask> <gateway> ] tuples.
   Remove additional routes by specifying no arguments.
   If <gateway> is "", the route is direct to the interface
```

so if you are running multiple networks that are reachable on the same layer 2 (and yes you can do this without routers!) the syntax is

networksetup -setadditionalroutes Ethernet dest mask ""

Note that you have to determine which networkservice the routes apply to (wired, wifi, etc). And of course the naming conventions DO NOT MATCH output from ifconfig!

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

you may have to quote the  value if you have more than one interface type (say multiple wired interfaces).
Note also that networksetup requires that you define all routes in one command!!! So if you have multiple  static routes you use:

```
networksetup -setadditionalroutes <networkservice> dest1 mask1 "" dest2 mask2 ""
```

and so on.